# How to repeat a UILocalNotification Sound

Tags: iphone, audio, uilocalnotification, repeat

How can I repeat a UILocalNotification sound?

```
-(IBAction) scheduleNotification1 {

    local1 = [[UILocalNotification alloc] init];

    // create date/time information
    local1.fireDate = [NSDate dateWithTimeIntervalSinceNow:2];
    local1.timeZone = [NSTimeZone defaultTimeZone];

    // set notification details
    local1.alertBody = @"2!";
    local1.alertAction = @"View";


    //local1.soundName = UILocalNotificationDefaultSoundName;
     //local1.soundName = @"alarmsound.caf";
    local1.soundName = @"29.mp3";
    // set the badge on the app icon
    local1.applicationIconBadgeNumber = 1;

    // local1.repeatInterval =NSSecondCalendarUnit;////    NSMinuteCalendarUnit;
    //local1.repeatInterval =1 ;
    // Gather any custom data you need to save with the notification
    NSDictionary *customInfo = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"ABCD2" forKey:@"yourKey1"];

    local1.userInfo = customInfo;

    // Schedule it!
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] scheduleLocalNotification:local1];

    //[local1 release];

}
```

Please provide some sample code.

Comment: What is your question ???? Will you please Elaborate your question ?

Comment: @a7mad what u want specify u r question

Comment: dear maulik ,    I need to repeat Sound Notification

Order to keep the sound is even pushing a button Notification

Comment: dear Ron , i need  repeat sound "29.mp3" Even user press button "View" in notifcation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry a7mad, I am afraid to say that but it is not Possible to Repeat the sound of UILocal Notification.I hope you have checked Other Questions Of SO. All of them have Negative result.

I can give you a suggestion to Call an Alert View Or ActionSheet on Click of "View" Button of LocalNotification and Continue your actions on that Controller as they can be controlled...

Comment: dear mac , Thank you to all what you said - but I loaded the application of App store  and repeat the process works and sound Notification -  application name "CrazyAlarm" and you can download and make sure that what I said

Comment: What CrazyAlarm might be doing is set mutiple LocalNotifications. Just after on is finished an other goes off.

Comment: @rckoenes :- Thanks what u have said is very True i guess.

Comment: thank rckoenes , I will search to Multiple LocalNotifications but i think it can work for repeat sound local notification

Comment: @a7mad :- Yes the Alternative that rckoenes had told is the only way, which beahaves like it is repeating but actually it is done but invoking multiple Notifications one after another and releasing the Previous Notifications in notice.

Comment: Yes what you say is true

Thank you all

Comment: I told you that it is not possible, as i have also asked this question but EveryOne's response was Negative. But if you still trying and if you get any Positive Reply, Please do tell to me. :))